# Ereader for my app

Tags: ebook-readers, ebook-management

I am looking for an ereader to incorporate in my app. I know lots of work has been done in this area and would not want to re-invent the wheel. Any good suggestions of open-source ereaders that can be picked up and then customised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-known engines are:

- [Readium](http://readium.org/)
- [Epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/)
- [CoolReader](https://www.openhub.net/p/crengine)